# Can you have 2 different suites in 1 JUnit TestCase Class?

Tags: junit

I'd like to define two different suites in the same JUnit TestCase Class; one for behaviour tests and another for efficiency tests. Is it possible?

If yes, how? If not, why not?

Additional details: I'm using JUnit 3.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to partition your tests. Suites, on their own, are not really the mechanism you need, rather it's JUnit's categories you need to investigate:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/closer-look-junit-categories

I've not used these as I've usually found the overhead of test partitioning too much effort, but this may work for you. I think TestNG has supported this concept for quite a while.

Also, if you're using Maven you get a partitioning of tests into unit and integration tests for free - check out the Failsafe plugin - which is good for separating tests you want to run quickly as part of every build from longer running tests.

Comment: I'm using JUnit 3.8.1 at this moment.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use the latest version? All your old tests should still work.